# Fastest way to multiply a static sized vector with a static sized constant non-square matrix in C, producing a 15-element output vector

Tags: c, performance, matrix, optimization, matrix-multiplication

I have a large `float` matrix, `A`, about 100000 in column length and 15 in row size.

Then we have a `uint8_t` vector `X` that has row size 100000. Both `A` and `X` have static sizes and never ever going to change in size.

`X` can change its values but `A` remains constant.

So what is the most absolute fastest way in C to compute `A*X`, producing a 15-element product vector?
Is it a good way to write something like this, instead of using a for-loop?

```
 A(0,0)*X(0) + A(0,1)*X(1) + A(0,2)*X(2) + ... +  A(0,n)*X(n)
 A(1,0)*X(0) + A(1,1)*X(1) + A(1,2)*X(2) + ... +  A(1,n)*X(n)
 ......
 A(m,0)*X(0) + A(m,1)*X(1) + A(m,2)*X(2) + ... +  A(m,n)*X(n)
```

Comment: When A values are set ?

Comment: @Ôrel Yes. They all are values.

Comment: I think @Ôrel meant to ask if many A values were `0.0`, making it sparse.  (Or if there's any other limitations, like A values being either 0 or 1 so the row x column dot products reduce to a masked sum.)

Comment: @PeterCordes No. the `0,0` is the index of the matrix.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added `float` to the question

Comment: I know `A(0,0)` is the index, I'm familiar with Fortran syntax (which you're using in a C question for some reason).  I assume the answer is still no that most elements aren't `0`.

Comment: Multiplications with `double` are faster than multiplications with `float` (checked on my computer). The latter need conversions to `double` and back unless, of course, there is some command-line option I should have tried. See http://codepad.org/okuj27bV

Comment: @pmg: only if you do it wrong.  https://godbolt.org/z/zMddfh shows the OP's naive `mul.c` (from a comment) compiles to asm that uses `mulss` or `fmaddss`, no conversion to/from `double` because no `double` objects are involved in any of the expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your matrix is dense, not sparse.  (Not mostly `0.0`).  Also that it's not mostly composed of `0.0` and `1.0` elements; if that's the case turn it into a bitmap you can use for masked sums of the vector.

---

I assume these are `float` or `double` values, and that you want to run this on a typical modern machine, like x86-64 or AArch64, with SIMD.  A loop is probably *better* because you need the compiler to auto-vectorize for max performance, and that's more likely with a loop than fully unrolled code.

You probably want to use each SIMD chunk of `X[]` with each of 4 or so chunks of `A[][]` data, so `X[]` only has to be loaded into registers 4 times total.  Each row of `A[][]` is only read once, so there's no data-reuse possible for `A[][]`.

Cache-blocking could also reduce the number of times X[] data has to be fetched into L1d cache to 1 total.  But you probably don't want to write a single loop doing 15 sums in parallel.  Fetching 15 streams from A might be a bad idea, and x86-64 (without AVX512) only has 16 SIMD registers, so unless you carefully manually vectorize, a compiler might spill vector accumulators to the stack and introduce a store-forwarding bottleneck.

---

### Do not fully unroll: code-cache misses would hurt much more than loop overhead.

Compilers typically don't roll straight-line code back up into a loop, even when that would be better.  So you'd get a *huge* block of asm with no branches.  Instead of reusing the same loop body from the L1 instruction cache (or uop cache or a loop buffer), the CPU would have to fetch code from memory, costing bandwidth that competes with bandwidth for data.

---

**In practice you should call a BLAS library function: it will be heavily optimized with SIMD for the specific CPU in the system its installed on.**

Or not, according to the last update, `X` is `uint8_t X[]`.  I doubt there are BLAS libraries that can convert on the fly from `uint8_t` to `float`, but that's probably what you want to save memory bandwidth, instead of separately converting to a tmp `float` vector.  Although doing that + calling a good BLAS function would still be better than badly-vectorized code if your compiler doesn't do a good job with your pure C loop.

Unrolling to use each SIMD-vector of `X` data more times will be extra good, to amortize the conversion overhead over more times.  Like probably unroll by 8.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Do you think SIMD works on embedded systems as well? I'm talking about system that cannot have large applications and libraries.

Comment: The fastest way I comes to "fast" multiplication is this code:

Comment: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/LinearAlgebra/mul.c

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: It depends what CPU you use.  You can get ARM CPUs for embedded applications with Neon (SIMD) enabled.  Your question didn't say anything about what systems you were targeting, so like I said I had to make assumptions.

Comment: I like your answer anyway. Hmm..well, assume that we don't know anything about the hardware, excepet that the data can fit into the processor. I would use the mul.c file I linked because it's the most optimal way in that case?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: without `restrict`, your C version doesn't auto-vectorize with GCC or clang.  https://godbolt.org/z/zMddfh shows what they do for x86-64 (note lack of `mulps`, only `mulss`.  Or with gcc, scalar `fmaddss`).  It's probably possible to write something that auto-vectorizes with pure C decently, maybe with some unrolling in the source.  If you'd asked that in the first place, I could have answered that.  (Or just use a portable BLAS library).

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: your `mul.c` takes `float*` args, not `uint8_t*`.  Figure out what you want to ask, and what use-cases it has to be good for (e.g. compiling on an arbitrary machine with `gcc -march=native -O3` or similar compiler), and why you can't just use a BLAS library, then update your question.

Comment: I wrote a library (just connected some libraries and made them portable) for BLAS in C. Not sure how optimal it is when it comes to `A*X`. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/EmbeddedLapack

Comment: I can change `mul.c`. I just need matrix times vector only. No more. I only need speed.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: I meant a *good* optimized BLAS library that has `#ifdef` manual optimizations for most major platforms, not some naive `f2c` port of netlib Fortran reference implementation.  e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms#ATLAS.  BLAS is an interface, not a specific implementation.  https://godbolt.org/z/3ooj3o shows that GCC only auto-vectorizes a couple simple sub-cases of that naive `sgemv` (`mulps` only, no addition, so I guess just scaling something?), and clang doesn't auto-vectorize any.

Comment: Can you recommend a library for me that suits STM32? That would be perfect :)

Comment: Or why can't I just execute all row statments at once?

Comment: All row statements at once?  Because your STM32 (cortex-m) CPU is not even superscalar.  It can only be running 1 instruction at any one time.  Even a wide superscalar like AMD Zen2 can only start 6 instructions in the same cycle.  For you, each row statement (written this way) is 100k mul+add operations long, so it can't even do all of one statement "at once".  Remember, CPUs run asm, not C, so the time to execute a statement depends on how complex the expression in it is.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: I think STM32 seems to be Cortex-M microcontrollers, on the low end for ARM.  Some do have an FPU, though, including Cortex-M7F (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M7).  But I don't see a mention of SIMD floating point, only 8/16-bit SIMD arithmetic.  You'd want a higher-end ARM if Cortex-M7F isn't fast enough; higher-end ARMs with NEON could go *much* faster, like 4x as much work per clock cycle at least.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: https://developer.arm.com/solutions/hpc/hpc-software/categories/math-libraries might be relevant, IDK if they support ARM chips without Neon.  Or just try compiling OpenBLAS (linked from that page) or ATLAS.  Also, if you can use C++, Eigen can be good.  It's templated so it can optimize away constant sizes.  (But again for most of these, you might have to convert X to float separately, wasting memory bandwidth and cache footprint vs. doing it on the fly.  Eigen might manage to inline that conversion.)

Comment: I don't think I can use Eigen in STM32. Too large. I guess that a normal `for-loop` will solve the problem for me. At least solve, not optimize.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: Eigen is a template library, only the code you actually use ends up in your executable.  That could be somewhat large.  (Of course, it gets replicated at every call site, instead of factored out from functions that do the same computation, unless you put your own wrapper around it.)  However, if you don't have SIMD, there's maybe not a huge amount to gain beyond unrolling to use the same X value 4 or even 15 times in the inner loop.  Just use `restrict` to let the compiler optimize better for non-overlapping inputs / outputs.

Comment: I found one library that STM32 support. CMSIS. file:///tmp/mozilla_dell0/dm00273990-digital-signal-processing-for-stm32-microcontrollers-using-cmsis-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: Document AN4841